# push item into array one at a time

Tags: javascript, validation

Is there anyway i can push more letter into the array and call them faster?  I'm trying to code a validation form .......  This works but it run one at time and moves to another when the condition is satisfied or input validated or not validated . Thats after click on submit... i need support in javascript. You can check the pic here.  https://prnt.sc/g8IKHTGdF1s2... I was thinking of using while loop or for loop to add items (a, b etc)  to the array but got stucked , dont know where to start

```
const errorsFVEd = () => {
  let errors = [];                                     


  const fnames = firstNam.value.trim();
  const lnames = lastNam.value.trim();
  const addys = Addy.value;
  const cits = CitNam.value;
  

  if (!isRequired(fnames)) {
    errors.push("a");
  } else if (!isAlphabet(fnames)) {
    errors.push("b");
  } else if (!isAlphabet(lnames)) {
    errors.push("d");
  } else if (!isRequired(lnames)) {
    errors.push("e");
  } else if (!isRequired(addys)) {
    errors.push("f");
  } else if (!isRequired(cits)) {
    errors.push("g");
  } else if (!isAlphabet(cits)) {
    errors.push("h");
  } else {
    console.log(1);
  }
  return errors;




}


function validaForm() {
    
    let errors = errorsFVEd();
  
  if (errors.length == 0) {
      
    document.getElementById("signup").submit();
      
  }
  else {

      
    for (i = 0; i < errors.length; i++){
      if (errors[i] == "a") {
        document.getElementById("error-first").innerHTML = "First name required.";
      } else if (errors[i] == "b") {
        document.getElementById("error-first").innerHTML = "Only alphabets allowed";
      } else if (errors[i] == "d") {
        document.getElementById("error-last").innerHTML = "Last name required.";
      } else if (errors[i] == "e") {
        document.getElementById("error-last").innerHTML = "Only alphabets allowed.";
      }else if (errors[i] == "f") {
        document.getElementById("error-addy").innerHTML = "Address required";
      } else if (errors[i] == "g") {
        document.getElementById("error-city").innerHTML = "City required";
      }else if (errors[i] == "h") {
        document.getElementById("error-city").innerHTML = "Invalid city";
      }else {
        console.log(1);
      }
      
      
    }
     
      
      
  }
      
  
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I didn't see the form, but I guess that it is something like the below example. Here I make use of the attributes `required` and `pattern`. A pattern is a regular expression and it is used for testing if the input is OK or not.

The second thing are the event listeners for the events `input` and `invalid`. So, on invalid the class name `invalid` is added to the input element (when trying to submit) and when starting to input something it is removed. This will make the span element show and hide.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('submit');
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
}, true);
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.error {
  display: none;
}

input.invalid+span.error {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>First: <input type="text" name="first" pattern="^\S{2,200}$" required>
<span class="error">Only characters allowed (between 2 and 200).</span>
</label>
  <label>Last: <input type="text" name="last" pattern="^\S{2,200}$" required>
<span class="error">Only characters allowed (between 2 and 200).</span>
</label>
  <label><button>Submit</button></label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks sir, i fixed it the last time with for loops